# How to assign a weight to the edge passing through more than one node in networkx python

Tags: python, graph, artificial-intelligence, networkx, shortest-path

I am new to networkx and i have read that edges are between two nodes and weights can be assign to them which can be done by this

```
    import networkx as nx
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edge(1,2)
```

this assigns weight 0.9 between node 1 and 2 but i have the data in which i don't have distances between two nodes rather i have distance between more than one node. e.g

```
 nodes with edges          weight
 1 -> 2-> 3-> 4 =============10
 1-> 3 -> 4   ============== 12
 3-> 4-> 5   ============== 20
```

i want to put data in networkX graph and find the shortest path between any two given nodes.

Any other suggestion to deal with data to get shortest path is welcome.

Comment: *"i don't have distances between two nodes rather i have distance between more than one node"* - I'm not sure that makes sense. So, the weights between node **1-3** or **3-4** is 0, but between **1-3-4** it's 12? Or is it that you don't know the weights between node **1-3/3-4**?

Comment: @Johan weights are not zero but I don't know the weights

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I don't know about the `networkx` package but you could solve it with a [Gauss elimination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) algorithm and use the result as weights.